# When to use @Version and @Audited in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Could someone help me with the use case when to use `@Version` and `@Audited` in Hibernate?

Comment: This discussion helped me understand why to use @Version 's optimistic locking https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/TransactionJTA_Overview-Pessimistic_and_optimistic_locking.html

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`@Version` is used to implement [Optimistic locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) with Hibernate, which means that no two transactions override the data at the same time with a conflict.
If the data is read by two threads at the same time, and both try to update the same row with different values, 
Hibernate uses the `@Version` field to check if the row is already updated.
Before committing, each transaction verifies that no other transaction has modified its data.
If modified, the last transaction encounters a "Working with stale data" error.

`@Audited` is used to perform [auditing functionality](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#migration) on entities part of Hibernate [Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html)

Answer (score 23):

`@Version` - is used to implement optimistic locking, see [*2.2.1.2. Versioning for optimistic locking*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-entity). Optimistic locking is useful when you don't expect many concurrent writes and don't want to pay the price of database locking.

`@Audited` - comes from [Envers API](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html) and can be used to automatically track changes to entities in a separate auditing table. Use Envers to keep the history of changes of some of your entities.